# About google protobuf dynamic link error

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

On windows, I use google protobuf2.5 in our project. But a link error happen.
In "generated_message_util.h",
`LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT  extern const ::std::string kEmptyString`.
someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the protobuf runtime. Pass `-lprotobuf` to the linker.